# How to add Sentry Source Map for Electron App

Tags: electron, sentry, source-maps

I have an electron app and I use Sentry for error tracking. I am not using webpack in my electron app and I would like to generate the map files and upload them and test them.
It seems I have quite fundamental understanding of this as I cannot even generate the map files? Tried going through the Sentry documentation but it was no use for me.
Any idea how I can do it step by step? Also how can I test it to ensure it works properly?
Really appreciate it.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am facing the same problem and I would really appreciate any hint. Thank you in advance

Comment: I couldn't get it to work either. Source maps were uploaded according to the CLI, but everything was still the same on Sentry.